# PHP echo database result

Tags: php, html, mysql, tinymce

Im trying to store and get HTML data made with tiny mce into database using PHP.

Its giving me this error: Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Here is what ive tried:

save.php

```
<?php
        include "functions.php";
        $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
        update_field($data);
```

show.php

```
<?php 
        include "functions.php";
        search_field();
```

functions.php

```
<?php

function connect(){
    return $yhteys = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "harjoitus20");
}

function search_field(){
    $result = connect()->query('SELECT sisalto FROM Taulu WHERE nimi="harkka"');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {   
        echo $row;
    }
}

function update_field($data){
    connect()->query('UPDATE Taulu SET sisalto="$data" WHERE nimi="harkka"');
}
```

Been trying to figure this out for a while now so any help would be appreciated.

Edit: In database it says $data in sisalto but shouldnt there be the content of my textarea?.

Comment: you are mixing mysqli with mysql

Answer (score 0):

try to use echo before connect() , like this

```
echo connect()->query('UPDATE Taulu SET sisalto="$data" WHERE nimi="harkka"');
```

it might solve your issue

Comment: Its just printing the number 1

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {   
            echo $row['sisalto'];
     }
```